# Rails admin gem, polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

How to get the queried data having polymorphic association

I have an 3 models

````
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end```

Employee and Product have column **is_active**.
In rails admin dropdown. I want to display the data where employee and product is **is_active = true.**

Have tried multiple ways to achieve this.
Please let me know if there is any solution?
````

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom scope in picture model as below:

```
scope :list_active(imageable_type), -> {
    where(imageable_type: imageable_type)
    .joins("INNER JOIN #{imageable_type.pluralize} ON 
           {#imageable_type.pluralize}.id = imageable_id AND 
             imageable_type = '#{imageable_type}'")
    .where('#{imageable_type.pluralize}.is_active = ?', true)
  }
```

Then you can simply list and use the response:

```
result = []
result << Image.list_active('Employee')
result << Image.list_active('Product')
```